# QGIS - automatically export multiple maps varying only the symbology source column

Tags: qgis, export, print-composer

I have a polygon shapefile where each row represents a sampling grid cell, and each column represents a species, which may be either present or absent in each cell. I need to export one map for each species. The map has no legend, just the grid and a basemap. My solution so far is go to symbology, select a species (column), go to the composer, export image, repeat.

This seems like it should be a fairly common workflow, so I was wondering if there might be some automated way to do it that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I managed to figure out how to do this with the Atlas feature, it may be useful for someone else:

First, I created a table (I just created a csv file in Excel) with a single column, with every species on my shapefile (so, one line for each column of the attribute table of the shapefile I want to build the maps for, and in the lines of the new table the column names of the attribute table).

Then I created an Atlas, and chose that table as the coverage layer.

Then, in the layer properties, in symbology, I selected categorized, and in "Column" I wrote eval(@atlas_pagename). And that's it, now each Atlas feature corresponds to a species.

Comment: I don't think you need the `eval()` function. Just `@atlas_pagename` should work.