# Performing (semi)automatic export of several maps at once using QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, atlas, time

I am trying to do automatic export of several maps on weekly basis. There will be input data for every day of the week and on the end of the week I want to export 7 maps.

I tried the Temporal tool but it's far from automatic. There is a lot of work with joining the data (source: https://www.birdseyeviewgis.com/blog/2020/8/14/creating-a-covid-19-temporal-animation-with-qgis ).

I tried the Atlas option based on this Q/A: [QGIS - automatically export multiple maps varying only the symbology source column](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299510/qgis-automatically-export-multiple-maps-varying-only-the-symbology-source-colu) but it's not working for me since the CSV table isn't working as coverage layer (the option "guided by Atlas" in Item properties is greyed out despite the Generate an atlas checkbox is checked).

[image]

The map should be based on Czech districts and the data are one number for each district a day (okres=district):

[image]

The data can be modified, I can use date format, it can be in rows, doesn't matter.
I am using desktop QGIS 3.16.13